# Problems packing a .deb from autotools. (checkinstall, debhelper, ...)

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging, checkinstall, autotools

I'm currently building a large project that contains sources written in few languages such as C,C++ & Python. I recently managed to (painfuly) handle autotools to make a proper install. Next step is to create .deb because our project is meant to run on debian stretch.

I tried several ways to do this but i can't get it working whether the way.

Tree .deb generated by checkinstall :

```
    unpack/
├── etc
│   └── nina
│       ├── auto_blacklist.txt
│       ├── blacklist.txt
│       ├── conf
│       ├── keywords.txt
│       ├── rubbish_links.txt
│       └── whitelist.txt
└── usr
    ├── local
    │   ├── bin
    │   │   ├── geckodriver
    │   │   └── nina
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   └── python2.7
    │   │       └── dist-packages
    │   │           ├── nina.py
    │   │           ├── nina_py_installed_files.txt
    │   │           ├── Uinput_wrapping_module-2.0.egg-info
    │   │           └── uinput_wrapping_module.so
    │   └── share
    │       └── man
    │           └── man1
    │               └── nina.1.gz
    └── share
        └── doc
            └── nina
                ├── COPYING
                ├── doc
                │   ├── Doxyfile
                │   └── nina.1
                ├── README
                └── README.md
```

Tree .deb generated by debhelper (v9):

```
unpack/
├── etc
│   └── nina
│       ├── auto_blacklist.txt
│       ├── blacklist.txt
│       ├── conf
│       ├── keywords.txt
│       ├── rubbish_links.txt
│       └── whitelist.txt
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── nina
    ├── lib
    │   └── python2.7
    │       └── dist-packages
    │           └── nina.py
    └── share
        ├── doc
        │   └── nina
        │       ├── changelog.Debian.gz
        │       └── copyright
        └── man
            └── man1
                └── nina.1.gz
```

As you can see it's not quite the same (sic). I'm more or less understanding what `checkinstall` does : it runs make install commands and just get files outputs to place it where it's installing on **MY** machine. `debhelper` seems to be a way more proper tool here. (installing in `/usr/lib` and not `/usr/local/lib`, allow us to sign packages & so on.) and i'd prefer to use it but it's not working as expected to do.

And on **huge** plus on debhelper way is that it's actually handling dependancies specified in debian/control and stuff. But checkinstall doesn't.

What debhelper is not doing :

- Getting some binary (geckodriver) from internet source and placing it in /usr/bin
- installing an homemade python module

Those actions are performed in my Makefile.am by overriding `install-exec-local:` (& respectively `uninstall-local:`) methods and executing some bash commands.

**---**

So my question is : how could i keep best parts of those two packaging ways to made it "perfect" ?

Comment: This doesn’t answer your specific question, but I suggest you look at [Vincent Bernat’s pragmatic Debian packaging](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2016-pragmatic-debian-packaging) guide; it might well be a better fit for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading things from the internet is something a Debian package build is not supposed to be doing. If you use some 'build in clean chroot' helper, it may not even be able to do so. However, plain `dpkg-buildpackage` should be able to do so. If your autotools build system does the right thing, then nothing should be needed; otherwise, you'll need to add the necessary commands to an `override_dh_foo` command (see 'man dh' on that).

For Python modules, what you need to do is install the .py files from your build system, too, respecting $DESTDIR. If you do so, debhelper in `dh` mode should just DTRT.

If none of that worked, please produce a minimal version of your package that exhibits the problem; otherwise this is very much a crystal ball problem.

Answer (score 0):

I rethinked my `Makefile.am` thanks to you. And eventually managed to get something.

- Geting geckodriver

I am running the script to get it at `./configure` step, and placing it as a file dependency in .deb package by assuming it's on the packing system like this :

```
bindeptsdir = \
    $(prefix)/bin
bindepts_DATA = \
    /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

- Installing python module

$(DESTDIR) was indeed the solution here, now my python module is installed like this :

```
$(PYTHON) setup.py install \
    --root $(DESTDIR)
```

And it works fine appart from the fact that i must place this in my debian/rules : `override_dh_usrlocal:` else it's yelling at me because i'm installing files in `/usr/local`

I'd prefer not, but python is handling installation by itself, and i can't specify installation path. The other solution was to specify `--prefix $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)` instead of `--root...` but it's installing files in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is not in pythonpath.

**---**

Appart from python troubles final result works just fine with dpkg-buildpackage.